# Replacing a character in a string in batch?

Tags: string, batch-file, replace

Before I begin, I assure you, this is not a duplicate. I have read multiple solutions for replacing a certain character in a string, but that is not specifically what I want to achieve. I know how to replace `X` in the string `STUVWXYZ`, but instead I want to replace the `5th` letter with `A`. Example:

```
set p=5
set string=STUVWXYZ
set replacewith=A
```

How can I replace a character, defined in the position `p`, with a character defined in the variable `replacewith`? If this is not possible, is it possible to not use the `replacewith` variable, and replace the character with another fixed character?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just sandwich the replacement with substrings.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set p=5
set string=STUVWXYZ
set replacewith=A

:: get first %p% characters of string
set "left=!string:~0,%p%!"

:: remove %p%+1 characters for the right half
set /a r = p + 1
set "right=!string:~%r%!"

:: left + middle + right
set "string=%left%%replacewith%%right%"

echo %string%
```

If you want to do this more than once in a script, it might make sense to turn this into a subroutine like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set p=5
set string=STUVWXYZ
set replacewith=A

call :replace string %p% %replacewith%

echo %string%

goto :EOF

:replace <var_to_manipulate> <position> <replacement>
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=!%~1!"
set "p=%~2"
set /a r=p+1
set "left=!string:~0,%p%!"
set "right=!string:~%r%!"
endlocal & set "%~1=%left%%~3%right%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: I knew it had something to do with delayed expansion, but I got confused when I tried to add in the `replacewith` as I used `!` instead of `%` and from there, I just went mad, swapping random `%`'s for `!`'s. Thanks. And for some reason I can't accept your answer for four minutes, so don't fret. I'll do it as soon as SO let's me.

Comment: I especially like your edit, I was thinking of a subroutine but not using parameters, that makes it a lot easier to manipulate the process itself.

Comment: @blaizor I just realized I got the logic wrong.  I'm replacing W, not X.  Edit forthcoming....

Comment: I understand all of your subroutine code, but there is one thing that I wouldn't think is necessary. The second line. Why do you need to setlocal? You never endlocal for that locale, and you setlocal/endlocal within the subroutine.

Comment: Fixed.  It was using an index of 1.  Now it's an index of 0.  So 0 is the first letter, 1 is the second, etc.  That's the more traditional way of doing this sort of thing, right?  Re: `setlocal`, it keeps from junking up the environment after runtime.  [See this page](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) for an explanation why this is considered good practice.  I include `setlocal` at the top of just about every script I write.  I also always use a separate `setlocal` within my subroutines to limit the scope of any throwaway variables I use in them. That way I don't have to worry about conflicts.

Comment: ... and the subroutines I write are more easily plugged into other scripts without needing to consider whether a variable name has already been used.

Comment: Yes, it localises variables so you can use them repeatedly without conflicting, but I am trained in the habit of using it only when necessary - for it sets an `errorlevel` of `0`, does it not?

Comment: It does, but it's also more useful than `%errorlevel%`.  :)  I can't recall ever being inconvenienced by `setlocal` clobbering the `%errorlevel%`.  Most of the time when I'm testing `%errorlevel%`, I do it with conditional execution anyway.  `tasklist /v | find /i "java.exe" > NUL && running || not running` sort of thing.  `setlocal` doesn't interfere with that.  You can also manually set `%errorlevel%` with `cmd /c exit /b num` if you need to.

Comment: Ok :) I do use `delayedexpansion` often, but a few of my `errorlevel` statements have indeed been clobbered before. In any case, thank you again. This discussion is getting way too long and SO keeps prompting me to automatically move it to chat.